# Run commands on Docker container from Emacs

Tags: emacs, docker, docker-compose, spacemacs

I'm using emacs (spacemacs) and I'm using docker for development. How do I run my tests from emacs? like I do with terminal `docker-compose run web rspec` or whatever command.

Answer (score 2):

So this might not be the best solution but it does work.
With Spacemacs you can use the `shell` layer to run commands in the bash shell.
See [guide](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/shell) shell.

1. Edit `~/.spacemacs` so that the entry `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` has `shell` in the list.
2. Close then launch emacs again
3. Open your project
4. Type `SPC '` and a shell will open
5. I have an alias setup in my `~/.bashrc` with this `alias dt=". '/Applications/Docker/Docker Quickstart Terminal.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/start.sh'"`
6. Then I run docker commands by typing `dt` in the shell
7. Now I can run any docker commands `docker-compose run web [COMMAND]`